# Frequent traveller program

Tags: loyalty-programs, aeroflot

I am a frequent traveller with Etihad program, so I have miles there. Alitalia is in the Etihad Airways Partners program, so whenever I fly with Alitalia I still save my miles on the Etihad program.

Next month I have a flight with Aeroflot: looking at their loyalty program, they are in SkyTeam, which involves also Alitalia within the partnership.

How is it possible that flying with Alitalia I can be in two different loyalty programs?

Will I be able to use the miles with Etihad program?

Should I join the SkyTeam Alliance (but I didn't understand which of the "sub-alliances" I should apply for)?

How can I earn miles from these flights and enjoy them?

I am also in the Miles&More frequent traveller program, but I think for this flight it is useless.

Comment: I tried to find a better title for this question, but it is difficult to understand what you're actually asking here? Is the question whether you can Ethiad to award you points when you're flying with an airline that has a loyalty recognition arrangement with another airline that has a loyalty recognition arrangement with Ethiad? No, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: If you anticipate more flights on SkyTeam airlines, such as Aeroflop, then you might consider joining Alitalia's frequent flyer program and save your SkyTeam points there, perhaps even start putting your Etihad points there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most airlines belong to one of the three big alliances, in Alitalia's case Skyteam, but Etihad does not.  However, since Etihad is a large investor in Alitalia, they encourage flights with them by accepting their flights for mileage in the Etihad program.

That's it, really.  Or in simpler terms, Alitalia is friends with investor Etihad and fellow Skyteam member Aeroflot, but Aeroflot and Etihad don't know each other.